# React - useEffect is not setting all state properties without error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In my React frontend, I have a `useEffect` hook that seems to be not setting a property correctly. When I analyze the raw network call, I see the correct JSON. But from what I can tell, when I call `response.json()` in the `useEffect`, a property called `schedules` isn't getting set. The response is coming from a .NET core API, but I'm fairly sure that isn't the problem since the network tab is showing the data I'm expecting.

Can someone shed some light on what I'm missing? I can't seem to determine any particular reason why a specific property would be missed when the response JSON has the property.

Raw JSON in browser network tab:

```
{
"emailTemplateKey": 18,
"emailProfileKey": 6,
"name": "Test name #5",
"description": "Test description #5",
"subject": "Test subject #5",
"body": "Test body #5",
"query": "Test query #5",
"enabled": false,
"schedules": [
    {
        "emailTemplateScheduleKey": 11,
        "scheduleKey": 4
    },
    {
        "emailTemplateScheduleKey": 12,
        "scheduleKey": 1
    }
]
}
```

useEffect code:

```
useEffect(() => {
if (templateId !== undefined) {
  const fetchTemplate = async () => {
    const url = apiUrl(`/email-templates/${templateId}`);
    const response = await fetch(url);
    
    try {
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log("data", data);
      setTemplate(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error during response.json(): ", error);
    }
  };

  fetchTemplate();
}
}, [templateId]);
```

useState of template code:

```
const [template, setTemplate] = useState({
emailTemplateKey: null,
emailProfileKey: null,
name: "",
description: "",
subject: "",
body: "",
query: "",
enabled: false,
schedules: []
});
```

Console log of useEffect "data":

```
{
"emailTemplateKey": 18,
"emailProfileKey": 6,
"name": "Test name #5",
"description": "Test description #5",
"subject": "Test subject #5",
"body": "Test body #5",
"query": "Test query #5",
"enabled": false,
"schedules": []
}
```

Network tab preview
[image]

Network tab response
[image]

Request headers
[image]

Comment: In the try block, it's displaying the console.log that I posted above: Console log of useEffect "data"

Comment: The error might be caused by the JSON parser, if the data inside `schedules` is not properly JSON-encoded, though an empty array is still weird. Maybe share the Network tab screenshot and we can see if the data is in the correct form or not.

Comment: I'll do that, but I will say for immediate info that I took the raw data in the network tab and ran it through a JSON linter. The linter verified that it was valid JSON.

Comment: I just copied the data into a clean sandbox and it seems to be updating:
https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-forest-rx4png

Would love a sandbox of your own for this (just go to https://react.new and it will generate one for you)

Comment: Hmm.. interesting. The data seems to be correct. Just to be sure, can you upload the screenshot of the console.log too?

Comment: Also, could you also add the headers tab? your content-type might be incorrect so it parses the json as a string but messes up the nesting.

Comment: Please log `response` variable.

Comment: Or please use const text = await response.text(); and then log text.